# How to modify array single subdocument without loading that entire array in-memory?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using Node.js `v8.12.0`, MongoDB `v4.0.4` & Mongoose `v5.3.1`.

I want to update an embedded array subdocument without changing its position in array index. And **without loading the entire array in memory** because that array might get very big in future.

---

I spent a lot of time searching how to achieve this but without luck.

I've tried to use Mongo's `$elemMatch` to load the document with only single relevant array subdocument, but that wouldn't let me save the subdocument in any practical way.

I've also looked into Mongoose array `set` method, but for this you need to have subdocument array index, so this mean I need to load the entire array into a memory and then find subdocument index.

Is there any way to achieve what I want? Ideally via Mongoose abstractions, so all Mongoose middleware like validations, plugins, etc. kick in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually found the answer right after submitting this question.

For anyone looking it up in future, you can use special `$` operator in combination with `$set`. (I'm not sure if that makes use of mongoose middlewares, though. I need to do some testing around that).

---

Here's some code example, which queries some subdocument using `_id`, and then updates that subdocument property `someProperty` using `$set` which uses special operator `$` that matches queried subdocument array position/index.

```
var doc = await SomeModel.findOneAndUpdate(
  {'someArray._id': 'xxx'},
  {'$set': {'someArray.$.someProperty': 'someValue'}},
);
```

It's still not 100% what I'm looking for, though. Because the returned `doc` still has full array of subdocuments (I assume that's still loaded into memory?), and it seems that I can't use `$elemMatch` in combination with `$set`.

---

In my case, further down the road, I'll probably redesign the database schema so these embedded subdocuments will be their own documents with just ObjectID reference to "parent" document.

---

Some resources:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-findOneAndUpdate